# Wrong output binary search program

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

In writing a BinarySearch program, I've written the program:

```
def binary_search(array, x, low=0, high=None):
    if high is None:
        high = len(array)
    while low < high:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        midval = array[mid]
        if midval < x:
            low = mid+1
        elif midval > x: 
            high = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return -1
```

When I put the following:

```
binary_search([1,2,2,3],2)
```

the output given by the program is

```
2
```

However, I would like the program to give as output the index of the first integer 'x' it finds. So in the previous example it would be '1' instead of '2'. Any idea on how I can alter this?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you aware that [the `bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) already provides binary search? `bisect_left` is does almost what you want (you'd just need to check the index returned to see if the value was found or not, since it returns the insertion point for the value even if the value isn't found). Also, naming a variable `list` is terrible practice, since it shadows the built-in `list` constructor.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes I am aware, but I am trying to write the program myself. Good point, I've renamed it array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the early out (the final `else` condition), replacing the prior `elif` with a straight `else`; only when the loop terminates do you test for equality and choose to return the index found or `-1` if it wasn't found:

```
def binary_search(array, x, low=0, high=None):
    if high is None:
        high = len(array)
    while low < high:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        if array[mid] < x:
            low = mid+1
        else: 
            high = mid
    return -1 if low >= len(array) or array[low] != x else low
```

It's also a good idea to behave this way because in general, you don't want to perform multiple comparisons per loop (`<` and `>` would each invoke comparisons, which could be expensive depending on the type); simplifying to exactly one non-numeric comparison per loop saves time (and often runs faster; Python libraries often hand implement `<` and `==`, and use wrappers to implement the other comparators in terms of `<` and `==`, making them slower).

This is actually what `bisect.bisect_left` does in [its pure Python implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/72946937536e/Lib/bisect.py#l67); it's otherwise nearly identical to your code. It makes it take longer, because it's more likely to take the full `log(n)` steps to identify the left most instance of a value, but the incremental cost is usually going to be small unless your input has *many* repeated values.

Comment: I like your solution! However, if I search for an element that isn't in the list, this program gives an error whereas my previous program gave a value '-1'. For example: binary_search([1,2,3],4) gives an error where I want it to give '-1'

Comment: @Whizkid95: I noticed that a minute before you posted; already fixed. :-) The error only occurred when the value was not in the `list` _and_ it was larger than all other elements in the `list`; for elements smaller than the maximum element, it behaved correctly.

Comment: Ah yes I see it now! Thanks a lot:)!!

Answer (score 0):

Given `[1,2,2,3]` the line `mid = (low+high)//2` is evaluated for the first run as:

```
mid = (0 + 4) // 2   ==> 2
```

Than `array[mid]` satisfies the condition (its value is exactly 2), and the index returned is mid (2).

```
if midval < x:
    ...
elif midval > x: 
    ...
else:
    return mid
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all. Floor division is the only rounding mode Python offers for integer division, and even if it could be changed to ceiling division or round nearest or whatever, it wouldn't change the behavior in a way that would reliably find the first instance of a given element.

Comment: It was just to explain where that output came from. The rounding mode is not the problem itself (The sentence is ambiguous, I'm going to remove that point).